# Reading Sequence File in PySpark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sequencefile

I have a sequence file whose values look like

```
(string_value, json_value)
```

I don't care about the string value.

In Scala I can read the file by

```scala
val reader = sc.sequenceFile[String, String]("/path...")
val data = reader.map{case (x, y) => (y.toString)}
val jsondata = spark.read.json(data)
```

I am having a hard time converting this to PySpark. I have tried using

```py
reader= sc.sequenceFile("/path","org.apache.hadoop.io.Text", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
data = reader.map(lambda x,y: str(y))
jsondata = spark.read.json(data)
```

The errors are cryptic but I can provide them if that helps. My question is, is what is the right syntax for reading these sequence files in pySpark2?

I think I am not converting the array elements to strings correctly. I get similar errors if I do something simple like

```py
m = sc.parallelize([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
m.map(lambda x,y: y.toString).collect()
```

or

```py
m = sc.parallelize([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
m.map(lambda x,y: str(y)).collect()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your code is the function you use. Function passed to `map` should take a single argument. Use either:

```py
reader.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

or just:

```py
reader.values()
```

As long as `keyClass` and `valueClass` match the data this should be all you need here and there should be no need for additional type conversions (this is handled internally by `sequenceFile`). Write in Scala:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sc
  .parallelize(Seq(
    ("foo", """{"foo": 1}"""), ("bar", """{"bar": 2}""")))
  .saveAsSequenceFile("example")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

Read in Python:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015 11:16:01)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

```py
In [1]: Text = "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"

In [2]: (sc
   ...:     .sequenceFile("example", Text, Text)
   ...:     .values()  
   ...:     .first())
Out[2]: '{"bar": 2}'
```

**Note**:

Legacy Python versions support tuple parameter unpacking:

```
reader.map(lambda (_, v): v)
```

**Don't use it** for code that should be forward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

For Spark 2.4.x, you've to get the **sparkContext** object from **SparkSession** (spark object). Which has the  ***sequenceFile*** API to read Sequence Files.

```
spark.
sparkContext.
sequenceFile('/user/sequencesample').
toDF().show()
```

Above one works like a charm.

For writing (***parquet*** to sequenceFile):

```
spark.
read.
format('parquet').
load('/user/parquet_sample').
select('id',F.concat_ws('|','id','name')).
rdd.map(lambda rec:(rec[0],rec[1])).
saveAsSequenceFile('/user/output')
```

First convert DF to RDD and create a tuple of *(Key,Value)* pair before saving as SequenceFile.

I hope this answer helps your purpose.